# Powershell Script to Rename files based on their date modified date. I'm really new to this

Tags: powershell

I would like to add an incremental number in front of my existing file names. However, I want to rename them based on their date modified information.

Comment: look for the cmdlets get-childitem with the property lastwritetime and the rename-item cmdlet on the msdn sites

Comment: Please show us that you have invested some effort and include your code in the question.

Comment: PLEASE, read the tour page for this site ... it will show you what you need to do to improve your Question. [*grin*] this ... Tour - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what pattern you exactly expect, here are 3 combinations

1. only with date + name

   ```
   Get-ChildItem -Path C:\examples -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Rename-Item -NewName { "$('{0:yyyMMddHHmmss}' -f $_.LastWriteTime) - $($_.Name)" }
   ```
2. increment + date + name

   ```
   Get-ChildItem -Path C:\examples -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | ForEach-Object -Begin { $inc = 1 } -Process {
      $_ | Rename-Item -NewName { "$inc-$('{0:yyyMMddHHmmss}' -f $_.LastWriteTime) - $($_.Name)" }
      $inc++
   }
   ```
3. increment + date

   ```
   Get-ChildItem -Path C:\examples -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | ForEach-Object -Begin { $inc = 1 } -Process {
      $_ | Rename-Item -NewName { "$inc-$('{0:yyyMMddHHmmss}' -f $_.LastWriteTime)" }
      $inc++
   }
   ```